# AngularJS: Preventing form submission until asyncronous validator is complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I want to prevent a submit button from being enabled while an async validator is running or will run.

I have a custom directive in which I am listening to the change event on an input. On this input element is an asynchronous validator that will fire when the input value change event is fired.

```js
input.on('change', function () {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(input.val(), 'change');
});

ngModel.$asyncValidators.modelValue = function () { ... }
```

The problem is that until the user un-focuses the input element, the async validator will not fire. This is an issue because the `$pending` field on the form does not update until the async validator fires. I want to be able to do the following to prevent the form from being submitted:

```html
<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pending" ng-click="form.submit()">Submit</button>
```

However, the form can still be submitted even though an async validator will run in the near future since $pending has not been updated yet as the user has not unfocused the input element. As long as the user stays focused in the input element the form will be allowed to be submitted.

What would be the correct way to handle this in AngularJS?

Comment: Is it "form" your form name?.

Comment: Try add a plunker or modify thisone: http://plnkr.co/edit/s4jJAOqehBkFUC9osMsy?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set a special scope param on `keydown` that will disable submit. Then turn it off when the async callback fires.

### js:

```
input.on('keydown', function () {
  $scope.needsValidation = true;
});

ngModel.$asyncValidators.modelValue = function () {
 ...
 $scope.needsValidation = false;    
 ... 
}
```

### Html:

```
<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pending || needsValidation" ng-click="form.submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: essentially did this without using the extra param in the ng-disabled directive. On keyup I set the viewValue on the ngModel causing the async validator to fire which updates the pending field on the form.

Comment: But then you fire the validator for every keypress, no?

Comment: In the keyup I set a timeout of 500ms and if no other keypress is detected before the timeout event fires I update the viewvalue and let the validator fire. If another keyup happens, I cancel the current timeout and begin again.